# SVN log error dates mismatch

Tags: svn

I tried to list the activities done in a SVN repository between the two dates using SVN log command. i have given date from 2012 to 2013 but it is giving output fo 2010 . Can somebody help on this

```
C:\Users\madsrini>svn log URL -r{2012-08-01}:{2013-02-21}
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1 | <USERNAME> | 2010-12-10 18:04:52 +0530 (Fri, 10 Dec 2010) | 1 line
```

Comment: Well, he has tried querying for revisions between August 1, 2012 and February 21, 2013, and is given a revision from 2010. Why that happens seems like a fair question to me.

Answer (score 1):

Plese, re-read [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.revs.specifiers.html), "Revision Dates" chapter

> When you specify a date, Subversion resolves that date to the **most recent revision of the repository as of that date**

and warning "Is Subversion a Day Early?"

> If you specify a single date as a revision without specifying a time of day (for example 2006-11-27), you may think that Subversion should give you the last revision that took place on the 27th of November. Instead, you'll get back a revision from the 26th, or even earlier.

Your log show (as requested): the most recent revision **before 2012-08-01** was 2010-12-10

Comment: Thanks . My requirement is to find the inactive repositories residing in the server for more than 180 days . how i could find that . Is there any SVN command

Comment: Only for that purpose i have started taking log revisions for each repository and using a perl script have to filter out name of the repository from the log this time i have tries to filter out the revison based on date and time again i am getting the same result.. Please find below

Comment: svn log -r {"2012-08-01 13:30"}:{"2013-02-21 13:30"} URL
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1 | <Name> | 2010-12-10 18:04:52 +0530 (Fri, 10 Dec 2010) | 1 line again i am getting the same result .

Comment: @user2094897 - you **really** have revision only from 2010 year really, can't see problem here. I'll prefer in your case to use `svn log -q -r HEAD <REPO-ROOT>` and parse date from this log-record for every repository or check `svn info <REPO-ROOT>`